# Constrain object keys to enum's values while not requiring all keys to be present and object values are not considered undefined

Tags: typescript, enums

*There are a lot of similar issues here but they don't cover the checklist at the end of the post (especially the "value being undefined" part).*

I have an enum

```
enum E {
  A = 'A',
  B = 'B'
}
```

Then I wanted to constrain my object value in state to `{ [key in E]: string }` but that requires me to instantiate the object already will all enum's keys. This is not allowed:

```
const state: { [key in E]: string } = {};
```

> Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type '{ A: string;
> B: string; }': A, B

So I tried to constrain it like this `{ [key in E]?: string }`. That allows me to omit enum keys, thus allows to instantiate empty object `{}` and also checks that key values are in enum's range:

```
state.A = 'x'; // ok
state.C = 'y'; // gives error which is nice
```

But then I encountered issue when forEaching Object entries

```
Object.entries(state).forEach(([key, value]) => console.log(value === undefined));
```

Typescript thinks that `value` can be of type `string|undefined` but that is never true.

When using only string as a key, the value is not considered undefined

```
const state: { [key: string]: string } = {};
```

[Playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAolDeAoKUCCUC8UDkrsBpkoAhTHY7RAX0VoGMB7EAZwBco2BDV4ALgSgBtANbAAnlACWIWAF0A-PzYAnaQHMoVMvCoBuWlx4A6dFmwAPbPoD01jq27AjAYTLYxV2gHkARgCtgOlYjUFZVYGYACkNgAEojADMGZRhOOgALSMiRcXwoADdOABswYFlYjAA+RhYGIqcihjVIwpLgTAwsMBAAE2AE6WAe2NjdIA)

---

How can I constrain object keys to enum values while their presence is not required and value is not undefined?

Checklist:

```
state.A = 'x' // ok
state.C = 'x' // error
Object.entries(state).forEach(([key, value])=>console.log(value.charAt(0))); // ok, no Object is possibly 'undefined'.(2532) error
```

TLDR: I want to get rid of the `assert` in the [Example here](https://codesandbox.io/s/empty-glitter-ps18k?file=/src/index.ts)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as typescript is concerned, having `A` omitted from the object is the same as having `A` explicitly set to `undefined`.  It's fine to do this:

```
const state: { [key in E]?: string } = {};
state.A = undefined;
```

@captain-yossarian has given you a good but very complicated way to prevent this behavior.  The easier thing to do is to simply filter out any `undefined` values.

This callback is a [type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards) which makes sure that the `value` in a `[key, value]` tuple is defined.

```
const isDefinedValue = <T,>(tuple: [string, T | undefined]): tuple is [string, Exclude<T, undefined>] => {
  return tuple[1] !== undefined;
}
```

We can then filter the `Object.entries` before using it.

```
Object.entries(state)
  .filter(isDefinedValue)
  .forEach(([key, value])=>console.log(value.charAt(0)));  // value is `string`
```

Comment: This is what I call: thinking out of the box

Comment: @captain-yossarian Your answer achieves exactly what they are asking for, it's just a shame that it's SO COMPLICATED to do that and has limitations.  I don't know if there's any better way to define the state how they want it.  Probably not.

Comment: Yes  the simplier- the better. I have tried to refactor my answer but without success. Personally I'm trying to use typeguards as much as possible

Answer (score 2):

```js
enum E {
  A = 'A',
  B = 'B'
}

type O = keyof typeof E
const state: { [key in keyof typeof E]?: string } = {};
```

If you want to make `state` mutable, just use `-readonly`:

```js
const state: { -readonly [key in keyof typeof E]?: string } = {};
```

> How can I constrain object keys to enum values while their presence is not required and value is not undefined?

Could you please provide some pseudo code?

Because, if key is not required, and you will try to get the value of non existence key, according to JS standard you should receive `undefined`

**UPDATE**

```js
enum E {
  A = 'A',
  B = 'B',
  C = 'C',
  D = 'D'
}

// credits goes to https://stackoverflow.com/a/50375286
type UnionToIntersection<U> = (U extends any ? (k: U) => void : never) extends (
  k: infer I
) => void
  ? I
  : never;

// //https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13298#issuecomment-468114901
type UnionToOvlds<U> = UnionToIntersection<
  U extends any ? (f: U) => void : never
>;

type PopUnion<U> = UnionToOvlds<U> extends (a: infer A) => void ? A : never;

type IsUnion<T> = [T] extends [UnionToIntersection<T>] ? false : true;

type UnionToArray<T, A extends unknown[] = []> = IsUnion<T> extends true
  ? UnionToArray<Exclude<T, PopUnion<T>>, [PopUnion<T>, ...A]>
  : [T, ...A];

type State<T extends string, R extends string[] = []> = {
  [P in T]: IsUnion<T> extends true ? State<Exclude<T, P>, [...R, Exclude<T, P>]> : R
}[T]

// Array of all possible keys
type Result = UnionToArray<State<keyof typeof E>>

// convert union to object with appropriate keys
type MapPredicate<T> = UnionToIntersection<T extends string ? {
  [P in T]: string
} : never>

// don't allow empty object because value can't be undefined
type Empty = { __tag: 'empty' }

// iterate through array of strings
type MappedString<
  Arr,
  Result = Empty
  > = Arr extends []
  ? []
  : Arr extends [infer H]
  ? Result | MapPredicate<H>
  : Arr extends [infer Head, ...infer Tail]
  ? MappedString<[...Tail], Result | MapPredicate<Head>>
  : Readonly<Result>;


// iterate through array of array of string
type MappedArray<
  Arr extends Array<unknown>,
  Result extends Array<unknown> = []
  > = Arr extends []
  ? []
  : Arr extends [infer H]
  ? [...Result, MappedString<H>]
  : Arr extends [infer Head, ...infer Tail]
  ? MappedArray<[...Tail], [...Result, MappedString<Head>]>
  : Readonly<Result>;

type AllPossibleValues = MappedArray<Result>[number];

const A: AllPossibleValues = { A: 'A' }
const AB: AllPossibleValues = { A: 'A', B: 'B' }
const ABC: AllPossibleValues = { A: 'A', B: 'B', C: 'C' }
const ABCD: AllPossibleValues = { A: 'A', B: 'B', C: 'C', D: 'D' }
const CD: AllPossibleValues = { C: 'C', D: 'D' }
const AD: AllPossibleValues = { A: 'A', D: 'D' }
const BD: AllPossibleValues = { B: 'B', D: 'D' }

const BE: AllPossibleValues = {} // expected error
const QA: AllPossibleValues = {A:'A', Q:'Q'} // expected error

const state:AllPossibleValues={A:'A'}


const x = Object.entries(state).forEach(([key, value]) => { /* [key: string, value: string] */

})
```

Pros: No assertions, no type castings

Cons: I have to similar Mapped utils which I don't know how to refactor. But it doe not affect your compiled code anyway. Also, if you add 5th property to enum, above code will not compile, because of recursion restrictions :)

So, if your object has less then 5 props, you are good to go.

TypeScript allows you roughly ~50 recursion calls.

If you have obj with 5 props, you should create union with `parseInt('11111',2)` 31 items. I think because my rec `MappedArray` calls rec `MappedString` I reached this limit faster.

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAolDeAoKUCCUC8UDkrsBpkoAhTHYgogYTOyspQBFbHtEBfRRAFwE8AHYFACqIAJYB7EABUJASRDdgAJwDOwAMbdJIADzCAfGQAUwqMAAeSkABNVUAIYheUAPxRjAawBcIgJSYRgBuEmI2UL4gwEEqAZbWdh5EPlBiIABmKlByiAEYwaE2RO45KJHRKgDcXAD0NVBUUjHK3PZg4lJQ3BJQEs0ANhIONsDh6e1aOjwCQqI6sgDyQf12%20kZYc1KyCkpqmtpSukRm8aCJTi7uxum%20wnkFYRFQUc2IBtXTglAAChL8m3pDGQAYtlqsgadbPZjA5fGlMso0PcoCFHu50OVmh8%20F85KoAbppOsoABtaQAXXMVjO9hJIPkihU6kmhyJlPc6Qc-XUT24yjAwGxMxEHRkElQymUDl4hPwaCpCTaIE8IAkAHcQCTKVgtcS8QSiQqaV1%20cBiiL5uLJdLdDALBp%20mARrKfn8DQYDHKSb9-qLCZ6oAA6YOockGIi%20Mly4OB0NCr4AZW4DiUhKNUKgqj5aQA5nKAErpxJZ5S5rVkXVkJAob2pEBQCm%20fV%20w2QxJ8gVuKBJlPAW32x3O6Ry74Bkkx-Nyu0Op194c-Axhp75jhk8m1eoSqUuCTpRz9fpQfgSVSqMQAI36Qk8wF4qk%20QnzwFUYH63GBotkW5tPdTN94u5dDMgEwB6G5QBoTQqO%207Q6F0PQSOeABW%20xQGqYjcAAFo4-D8Mofylr2UD-veOJCAAsg4-DfMooxiBovb%20h%20lo7Ey%20w6Gmbb2CWuZdtWpLfHWDbkr4PEgDmHBPC8KjhogdRQDYUjYO%20XKDGq5gQPwfC9MhqHnpoDhgDyQRcp2DEgMpUD6VA7QjOkaSjA%20sCadpWDwFAAD6HnJjmvjYMALm8NgUCcHJ9QYSoRFYfhYA5thDjWjue5iTmpHCpRuGjEmpbiUcKBboQKBPi%20b5kDAgVEMSW5FrS64oO4WoRmgko1aS8JZAAEnVXbFa%2074AD5QBlNF0QxqYdeGZTNYiXFtRknXAMM0bBu1iLSA4Yj9N17gZYINjZbmujjsG62beSBbPn1UCDcNtE2PRjEdYtNhgVNT7DFI-Qyr1b7vFwYWpLsUWYTFcWOIlvR7gl26Q5m2biU5u2jN%20MpENVs0o7o7QquqICekQP3vhjiVY8qqoasSjUoFVLWzVTXb0746PUhmJKrVAXXmsdgaE3KSP7fDOa6BN3VM7TLOJGz82Ik9S1Bit0sNhtW3mvzmPc6dW1ehOl1vnzVF7QduWyy9YZNe9ikgF9uiE39TlmG5oVOagB6-KeF5XgAaqZz5kGrJO2yS4AQPpyjkh8kEgFmaBM67J5npewDe46vtuTHOB4CFiCR9HqDELH-RuwnXs%20-YaeoH5eByvn5DBZwOfvnnVAF0XHtJ6XVbp7gBAkH5FBys3OD0FnDdoMQVCMC38dt8nAplwgXdV73tcD359BypPOCsCPUjRxPU-u4ns%20pwvg90D3m-YNv9e743m8u4X09Hx35eVxffnX9nt8kPfceHyXKd57uRrtgfuUBL6fy-lHd8xAYAH2Lu3QBVZ2BQHkpYQQWhRjmElBIZQUDo4AEUK5oD-gg4%20QCK7dzlAQ7w2ACHYBQWgiwGClDhBUPhPB%20D3xZl7N4B%20rdn6AIwPASheAnajwsGQBYuktCBlANmZ8xgeFKD8IGdIuCYAOA0JhYwxgST-jlCZFO5JkTuRqAAKlJP%20USgtDE%20xsTlHMlJzE1C4OwPw-1EBAA)

Comment: Maybe it's not implemented in typescript yet? But how can I get a value for non-existing key if I'm looping over entries (key:value pairs) `Object.entries(state)`?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/empty-glitter-ps18k?file=/src/index.ts There I have to use assert even though using `Object.entries()` should IMO rule out all `undefined` values.

Comment: @simPod please take a look, I made an update

Comment: Wow, exhaustive! Thank you and vote up! Though I'm a bit disappointed as I thought I'm only missing something. Forgotten `?` or `!` somewhere  While it looks like it's not trivial. I'll keep acceptance candy in my pocket for a little longer if you don't mind.

Comment: Sure, I will happy if somebody will find some better way to handle it.